# VB.NET to C# - my.computer.getfiles()

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is the equivalent C# code for this VB.NET code?

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(....)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The My class is VB.NET specific.

You can use the static methods of the System.IO.Directory class - e.g. Directory.GetFiles.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the VB.Net's "My" in C#.  It's all code, after all.  In your C# project, you'd simply add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic

You can check out a more detailed explanation here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MyNamespace.aspx

I don't think there is anything in 'My' that you can't achieve without using it; but just because you aren't programming in VB.Net you have to *not* use it.

Having said all that - most architect type people I know would roll their eyes at you if they saw you adding a reference to VisualBasic in a C# project.  But it's totally doable.

Comment: Agreed on both counts: doable, but an eye-roller.

Comment: Agreed.  Do it the C# way.  It's the harder way (yes it is, non-VB-ers), but count on Visual Basic support going away.  It will happen, IMO.  Just a question of when. This from a 20-year VB.NET veteran.