# what is the equivalent of My.Computer in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB.NET to C# - my.computer.getfiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909348/vb-net-to-c-sharp-my-computer-getfiles)

Can any one tell me the equivalent of following vb.net code 'My.Computer' methods in C#.?

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(oldname,newname)
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(filename)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're probably looking for `File`. `File.Open(` `File.Move(`...

Comment: Here check this link out - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielfe/archive/2005/06/14/429092.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)

> Use the File class for typical operations such as copying, moving, renaming, creating, opening, deleting, and appending to files. You can also use the File class to get and set file attributes or DateTime information related to the creation, access, and writing of a file.

You can use `System.IO.File` to do most of the things that my limited knowledge of VB said `My.Computer.FileSystem` could do.

The methods are still static, and take in the path of the file you wish to manipulate. So for the examples you provided...

```
File.Move(oldname, newname);  //File renames things just like Unix does- by moving them
File.Delete(filename);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reference the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` in C#. This DLL contains the `Computer` class in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.IO.File.Move(oldname,newname);
System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
```

See [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) and [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) classes.  The big difference is that `File` is used statically, (e.g. `File.Move(...)`) while `FileInfo` is used as an instance, allowing you to do many operations on one file more conveniently (e.g. `var file = new FileInfo(filePath); var extension = file.Extension;`).

Answer (score 2):

I never did understand why these were introduced in VB, but, for those two examples, [`File.Move(oldname, newname)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move) and [`File.Delete(filename)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)

Of course, both these methods also work in VB...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
System.IO.Move(oldFileName, newFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the namespace `System.IO`

Delete file is

```
File.Delete(string path);
```

Rename file is

```
File.Move(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is the most direct equivalent:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.Rename(oldname, newname)
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.Kill(filename)
```

In fact it uses VB's own FileSystem class, through, I am not sure if I would recommend using it since there are more C#-ways of doing it.

If you use it, be sure to add Microsoft.VisualBasic in references.

Answer (score 0):

The [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace is what you're looking for.